# How to not instantiate the feign client during tests?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, netflix-feign, feign

when I start my test the feign client also starts so how to not Instantiate the Feign Client During Tests ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Mockito to mock the feign methods. The feign client was instantiated but the methods dont call external APIs

Comment: and is there a solution to not instantiate it at all?

Comment: and is there a solution to not instantiate it at all?

Comment: It is a solution so that it does not interfere in the tests, I thiink so

Comment: do you have other solution as dependency or configuration ?

Comment: uhm Im not sure about this, but maybe you can use a config like this:

`
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
        "feign.hystrix.enabled=false"}
`